# How can you use assingInclude for include blocks that are inside an included block using TemplatePower?

Tags: php, templates

I'm new to TemplatePower. How can I use assingInclude for include blocks that are inside an included block using TemplatePower?

So for example, I use:

```
<!-- INCLUDE BLOCK block_1 -->
```

Then in PHP I use:

```
$tpl->assignInclude('block_1', 'block_1.tpl');
```

Then inside `block_1.tpl`, I want to use the same principle. For example:

```
<!-- INCLUDE BLOCK block_2 -->
```

And again in the PHP I use:

```
$tpl->assignInclude('block_2', 'block_2.tpl');
```

Why isn't it working?

Comment: @MasterCassim: The file is not included and I don't receive an error explaining why. When I look in the source code, the include block line is removed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you are using

```
<!-- INCLUDE BLOCK block_2 -->
```

But you have to use

```
<!-- INCLUDE BLOCK : block_2 -->
```

You have to use : in order to make it work